# aws cognito user pool domain - Invalid_Request

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have created a user pool and setup domain with app client settings () to host sign up and sign in pages in the cognito itself. When I tried using the url similar to -

https://myDomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=fkjfkasjfkasjfdweinfskfsfsfnk&redirect_uri=https://google.com

in the browser I am redirected to

https://myDomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/error?error=invalid_request#

Note: I tried using Cognito User Pool and Facebook identity providers without OAuth2 enabled.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 20):

It works for me with following User Pool settings.

```
App integration
    App client settings
        Enabled Identity Providers
            ☑ Facebook  ☑ Cognito User Pool
        Callback URL(s)
            https://google.com
        OAuth 2.0
            Allowed OAuth Flows
            ☑ Authorization code grant  ☐ Implicit grant  ☐ Client credentials
        Allowed OAuth Scopes
            ☐ phone  ☐ email  ☑ openid  ☐ aws.cognito.signin.user.admin  ☐ profile
```

Comment: Still This does not work

Answer (score 10):

You're doing everything correct from what you've describe, but you should check the following,

- Have you added `https://google.com` in App Client Setting as Callback URL?
- Have you checked your Identity Provider in `Enabled Identity Providers`?
- In `Allowed OAuth Flows`, you must have checked "Authorization Code Grant".

Comment: Checking the "Authorization Code Grant" worked for my but then you must also check "email" and "openid" under "Allowed OAuth Scopes".

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a required attribute (Name) that was set to `Mutable: False`.

After login user was prompted to reset their temporary password and set the name. 
On form submission, `An error was encountered with the requested page` error appeared.

Making the Name attribute editable fixed the issue.

Comment: This saved me. Where is this stated on AWS documentation?
Kudos to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/70384714/9671120

Answer (score 1):

Enable `Authorization code grant` under `Allowed OAuth Flows` in the `AppClientSettngs` tab

Change the redirect_uri like

https://myDomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=fkjfkasjfkasjfdweinfskfsfsfnk&redirect_uri=https://myDomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com

This worked for me