# AWS Cognito UI page returns generic error after sign in

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-cognito, load-balancing, amazon-ecs

Cognito UI responds to first password change with: **An error was encountered with the requested page.** I configured Cognito alongside an application load balancer (associated to a custom domain).

What I expect: to be redirected to my ECS Fargate service entrypoint, with auth headers attached -> [see here](https://aws-blog.de/2020/03/building-a-fargate-based-container-app-with-cognito-authentication.html).

Steps:

- I create a user in the userpool (as admin)
- I navigate to the custom url, which redirects me to Cognito UI
- I log in, and I am forced to reset password and provide fields
- I enter the new password and details
- As I submit the form, the error message above is returned

In the browser's dev tools:

- request: `POST https://{userpooldomain}.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com/changePassword?**params` -> `302`
- redirect: `GET https://{userpooldomain}.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com/error` -> `400`

There is no message with the error. Also, all systems appears to be healthy and the callbacks point to `https://service.mydomain.com/, https://service.mydomain.com/oauth2/idpresponse`
Where should I look further at?

Answer (score 0):

[Max Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60848995/9671120) gives me the way out.

The reason must be that as the fields are immutable, allowing the user to insert them (read: update them on their DB) crashes something. I would really appreciate anyone pointing me to anything in the docs where this is stated (or, could be classified as a bug?).